# VB6 Datareport issue on other computers

Tags: vb6

Hello I have created a installer package of my project build in Visual Basic 6.0. I have using Advance Installer for making package. every thing works perfectly on other systems but a minor problem in my project i am facing which is very hard for me to resolve is I am getting Run time error 372 when printing report i got this error every time

> Run-time error '372':
>
> Failed to load control 'DataReport' from C: \ WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \
>   Msdbrptr.dll. Your version of the C: \ WINDOWS \ SysWOW64 \
>   Msdbrptr.dll may be outdated. Make sure you are using the version of
>   the control That was provided with your application.

I am using version **6.0.81.69** of msdbrptr.dll 
and project is based on VB6 with Data report and MS Access

I don't know how to fix this issue please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you deploying MSStdFmt.dll as part of your package?  Many so-called "advanced" and "magical" installer tools are anything but.  Look for one that lets you package using Microsoft-supplied merge modules.

Comment: yes Its already included